# Gravar dados para ficheiro na memoria interna android

Tags: java, android

Preciso de gravar um conjunto de variaveis:

```
int var1,var2,var3
var4=new int[10], var5=new int[10], var6=new int[10]
var7=new int[5][3],var8=new int[5][3]
```

O meu objetivo era grava-las todas por ordem e depois ler ler-as todas pela mesma ordem. 
Pelos outros posts que vi, para gravar na memoria interna tenho que usar o `openFileOutput()` mas nao encontrei nenhum exemplo que me me explicasse como passar `array´s`, `arrays bidimensionais`. Alguem me pode indicar uma forma de resolver isto?

Comment: Uma alternativa seria usar uma WebView, e usar a função de gravar dados no dispositivo no html5.

Se escolher esta forma, talvez esse artigo possa te ajudar:
http://www.devmedia.com.br/atividades-basicas-ao-processo-de-desenvolvimento-de-software/5413

Answer (score 2):

Bom, não sei se entendi direito o que você precisa fazer. Mas vamos lá, pelo que eu entendi é que você precisa guardar valores na memória do android, mas precisa ser em um arquivo especifico? Senão, você pode só usar o SharedPreferences, que serve exatamente pra salvar pequenas quantidades de dados, dando pra cada uma, uma chave e adicionando seu valor.
Exemplo:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html?hl=pt-br

Mas se seu plano é mesmo salvar em arquivo:

```
String FILENAME = "hello_file";
String string = "hello world!";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

Na dúvida, da uma olhada aqui, sobre métodos de armazenamento :

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html